# Text won't wrap correctly when using padding-left

Tags: html, css

Each link in the menu on the left has `padding-left: 15px;` the reason for this is so I can add a background image (the blue arrow).

But now, when the text wraps (see "Paintings, prints, and watercolours"), it ignores the padding.

After searching around I can't find any similar cases at all, is that because I am going at this wrong?

If what I have at the moment is fine, how can I fix the wrapping issue?

Comment: set `padding-left` to <p> element.

Comment: @emilan I can't do that because then the background image (the arrow) will be padded as well.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Padding only applies to block-level elements.  Either assign your menu's `a` elements a `display:block;` or `display:inline-block;` to get them to respond properly to padding.

Answer (score 1):

You should place the padding on a div instead - http://jsfiddle.net/qHGrJ/1/

Paddings don't work that way for span style elements. Alternatively you could probably use display:block on the link.

Comment: The links weren't acting as links in that example, check this updated version too http://jsfiddle.net/qHGrJ/2/

Answer (score 0):

Given the way you're using these anchors you can just set them to `display:block`.

A more ideal way to mark up this menu (especially since you're using HTML5) would be to use a `menu` tag containing a list of links.

```
<menu>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="myMenuItem.html">My Menu Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="mySecondMenuItem.html>My Second Menu Item</a></li>
</ul>
</menu>
```

This is more semantic and also gives you the `li`'s as hooks to add a margin to.

Answer (score 0):

Add display:block to your anchors. I would suggest against using inline-block as it isn't fully supported cross-browser (i believe IE7 and below).

Add display block on line 13 of view.css like so

```
#auction_cat_menu p a{ padding-left:15px; white-space:pre-wrap; display: block;}
```

Comment: Sam: There is actually an inline-block css hack that does make it render properly across browsers, including IE7.